# Spring aop aspects not executing on annotations

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm developing a WebSocket server application using spring.
Class PlayerHandler

```
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by kris on 11.07.16.
 */
public class PlayerHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler{
    public PlayerHandler(){}

    @Override
    @AuthorizationRequired
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage tm) throws IOException {
        session.sendMessage(tm);
    }
}
```

I want user to be authorized with every incoming request by token, so I created a Aspect UserAuthorization

```
package com.berrigan.axevor.authorization;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Aspect
@Component
public class UserAuthorization {
    @Around("@annotation(com.berrigan.axevor.authorization.AuthorizationRequired)")
    public void authorize(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
         System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\Works\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        jp.proceed();
    }
}
```

I added the @AuthorizationRequired annotation, which indicates methods in which users are going to be authorized. Unfortunately method authorize never get called. I've added following code to my main class to check if the bean get created.

```
UserAuthorization ua = ctx.getBean(UserAuthorization.class); // ApplicationContext
if(au == null) System.out.println("is null")
```

But I don't get such log. 
My spring config

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Import({com.berrigan.axevor.websocket.WebSocketConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.berrigan.axevor"})
public class Config {}
```

Annotation code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AuthorizationRequired{}
```

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket

```
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addHandler(playerHandler(), "/game").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler playerHandler(){
        return new PlayerHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's see your annotation. Post a [mcve] while you're at it.

Comment: Yeah, this all works fine for me, with some basic assumptions. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This code should be runnable, i'm using spring-boot to run it

Comment: You haven't shown a bean declaration for `PlayerHandler` or how you retrieve and use that bean. We don't know what `WebSocketConfig` and all other types are.

Comment: Edited answer, it is just standard websocket configuration

Comment: Show us also how you retrieve that `PlayerHandler` bean and how you try to use it to determine that your AOP isn't executed.

Comment: That bean is used only in WebSocketConfig there is `PlayerHandler` code posted

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, corrupted pom.xml file. After regenerating it, everything works like a charm

Comment: I am also trying to do something similar, however I am unable to get the @Before advice being invoked before handleTextMessage(), Can you share what fix have you done in your pom.